# Web Scraping Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape shopee.co.id using BeautifulSoup and Selenium. I successfully scrap a page of search results page using the code below:

```
import imp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options     
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from time import sleep
from collections import Counter
import json
from turtle import delay
import requests
import time

# create object for chrome options
chrome_options = Options()

# Customize chrome display
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1365,4597.190")
webdriver_service = Service(path)
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')      

# create webdriver object
path = '/Applications/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=chrome_options)

# scrape a page of search result
# get url
url = 'https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=obat%20kanker'
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "shopee-search-item-result")))

driver.execute_script("""
        var scroll = document.body.scrollHeight / 10;
        var i = 0;
        function scrollit(i) {
           window.scrollBy({top: scroll, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
           i++;
           if (i < 10) {
            setTimeout(scrollit, 500, i);
            }
        }
        scrollit(i);
        """)
sleep(5)
html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Scrape product name

product_name = soup.find_all('div', class_="ie3A+n bM+7UW Cve6sh")
product_name[0].get_text()

product_price = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'ZEgDH9'})
product_price[0].get_text()

product_sold = soup.find_all('div', {'class':"zGGwiV"})
product_sold[0].get_text()
```

However, I failed to scrap all the search results which shows in 50 pages by looping it in code below:

```
# scrape all search results in 50 pages
product_name, product_price, product_sold, product_city = [], [], [], []

for page in range(0,51):
    search_link = 'https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=obat%20kanker&page={}'.format(page)
    driver.get(search_link)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "shopee-search-item-result")))

    driver.execute_script("""
            var scroll = document.body.scrollHeight / 10;
            var i = 0;
            function scrollit(i) {
            window.scrollBy({top: scroll, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
            i++;
            if (i < 10) {
                setTimeout(scrollit, 500, i);
                }
            }
            scrollit(i);
            """)
    sleep(5)
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    # Scrape product name
    for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='ie3A+n bM+7UW Cve6sh'):
        product_name.append(i.text)

    # Scrape product price
    for item in soup.find_all('span', class_='ZEgDH9'):
        product_price.append(i.text)
       

    # Scrape total product sold
    for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='zGGwiV'):
        product_sold.append(i.text)
```

I got this error when I tried to scrap all the 50 pages of search results by looping:

```
> Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text
> editor
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in
> _new_conn(self)
>     173         try:
> --> 174             conn = connection.create_connection(
>     175                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
> 
> /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py
> in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
>      94     if err is not None:
> ---> 95         raise err
>      96 
> 
> /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py
> in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
>      84                 sock.bind(source_address)
> ---> 85             sock.connect(sa)
>      86             return sock
> 
> ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
> in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
> assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked,
> body_pos, **response_kw)
>     702             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
> --> 703             httplib_response = self._make_request( ...
> --> 592             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
>     593 
>     594         log.debug("Incremented Retry for (url='%s'): %r", url, new_retry)
> 
> MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=51516): Max
> retries exceeded with url:
> /session/82c5c00635782b7cec5f04ad50523423/element/388321eb-3009-474d-b38c-915ac8477eab/text
> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection
> object at 0x13edcdeb0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
> 61] Connection refused'))
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: maybe server has complex system to detect bots/scripts and it blocks you. Or maybe it is only problem with Selenium.  Maybe you should run without `--headless` to see what page is displaying.

Comment: @furas unfortunately running it without `--headless` doesn't fix it. Change some order of the chrome display and it works now. Thanks anw!

Comment: it was not to fix it but to see what browser is doing - it may show what is the problem

Comment: if you resolved problem then you could describe it with details as answer below. It can help other people. And later you can mark your answer as accepted

Comment: @furas I just move the `webdriver_service = Service(path)` after `path = '/Applications/chromedriver'` then it works

Comment: it strange - code `Service(path)` before `path = ...` should generate different error: `path not defined`.

Comment: @furas i think so too. i also have no idea that i was so careless to put the `path=..` after the 'Service(path)` the first time. anw it works now so everything's good.

Comment: you may describe all this as answer below and later you can mark your answer as accepted.